# Spliiting a string of names in R and then grouping by all possible permutations

Tags: r, split, grouping

I have some data with names of basketball players on the court at one time in one column in the following format:

"@ A.J. Price @ + @ Chase Budinger @ + @ Alexey Shved @ + @ Luc Mbah a Moute @ + @ Shabazz Muhammad @"

These names are not in any particular order and could change between game entries.  I want to group by this lineup but include other possible combinations that amount to the same five guys on the court.

So let's say I have data like this smaller example:

```
team <- data.frame(names = c("@ Name One @ + @ Name Two @ + @ Name Three @",
                         "@ Name Two @ + @ Name Three @ + @ Name One @",
                         "@ Name Four @ + @ Name Five @ + @ Name Six @",
                         "@ Name Five @ + @ Name Four @ + @ Name Six @",
                         "@ Name One @ + @ Name Three @ + @ Name Two @"),
                       minutes = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

There are two combinations of names here, with the names in different orders on different rows. One combination includes `@ Name One @ + @ Name Two @ + @ Name Three @`, the second combination includes `@ Name Five @ + @ Name Four @ + @ Name Six @`.  I want to sum minutes by each those two only.

My initial thought was to create a dummy variable for each possible name and figure out some way to group by all possible combinations of these columns and then eliminate the ones that don't have entries; but, I am sure that one of the smart people on here knows a better way.

Comment: Can you update with the expected output for the example you provided?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What 2 combinations are you referring to, for example? You mention something about 5 guys, but there are 3 guys per row and 6 guys in total, so please explain.

Comment: The actual data has 5 guys, but I just made an example data frame of three to make it easier to show the concept.  The two combinations in the example are just the two groups of names that are in the data frame in different orders.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
team$names = strsplit(gsub(' ?\\@ ?', '', team$names), '\\+')

# Sort to account for permutations (Note that elements are type 'list')
team$names = lapply(team$names, sort)

# Collapse into type 'character' for 'aggregate'
team$names = sapply(team$names, paste, collapse=',')

aggregate(minutes ~ names, team, sum)

#                          names minutes
# 1 Name Five,Name Four,Name Six       7
# 2 Name One,Name Three,Name Two       8
```

Answer (score 2):

My favorite tidyverse way is to use a list column, which you can easily create with `strsplit` and iterate over with `purrr::map` (or `*apply`, if you prefer):

```
library(tidyverse)

team %>% 
    mutate(names = strsplit(as.character(names), '[@ +]{2,}'),    # split to list column
           names = map(names, sort),    # sort each
           names = map_chr(names, toString)) %>%    # and coerce it back to a string
    group_by(names) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)

## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##                              names minutes
##                              <chr>   <dbl>
## 1 , Name Five, Name Four, Name Six       7
## 2 , Name One, Name Three, Name Two       8
```

There are extra commas at the beginning due to the split, but get rid of them with `gsub` or `na_if` and `na.omit` or whatever other method you like.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I haven't used purr::map much.  I'll have to read up on it.

Comment: `map` is equivalent to `lapply` (with some extra conveniences built-in), and `map_chr` is like `sapply` that simplifies to character (really, `vapply`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(team, names, sep="[@+ ]") %>%
           filter(names !='') %>% 
           group_by(minutes) %>% 
           summarise(names=toString(sort(paste(names[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
                              names[c(FALSE, TRUE)])))) %>% 
           group_by(names) %>% 
           summarise(minutes = sum(minutes))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
#                              names minutes
#                              <chr>   <dbl>
#1 Name Five, Name Four, Name Six       7
#2 Name One, Name Three, Name Two       8
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It seems odd to group by minutes in order to summarise the names.  What if you had a case with different lineups having the same number of minutes?

Comment: @tenkev82 I would add `tibble::rownames_to_column(team, var="ID") %>% separate_rows(names, sep="[@+ ]+) %>% filter(names !="") %>% group_by(ID) %>% ...`